# R markdown flex dashboard not producing plot that works in regular R script

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I have a plot that works correctly in a regular R script, but as soon as I try to run it in a flex dashboard with an inputSelect() based on the values in a "Name" column, I get no plot at all. Instead I get "Error: [object object] where the plot should be. The code that works in the regular R script generates a blank plot with no error message when used in the rmd file in place of the selectInput() and original plot code. The attached code is my dashboard file dataset, rmd dashboard code, and the dataset and code that work in a regular R script . Any help would be appreciated!

## dashboard dataset

```
`structure(list(Date = c("2/20/2023", "2/13/2023", "2/6/2023", 
"1/30/2023", "1/23/2023", "1/16/2023", "2/20/2023", "2/13/2023", 
"2/6/2023", "1/30/2023", "1/23/2023", "1/16/2023", "2/20/2023", 
"2/13/2023", "2/6/2023", "1/30/2023", "1/23/2023", "1/16/2023"
), Name = c("Name 1", "Name 1", "Name 1", "Name 1", "Name 1", 
"Name 1", "Name 2", "Name 2", "Name 2", "Name 2", "Name 2", "Name 2", 
"Name 3", "Name 3", "Name 3", "Name 3", "Name 3", "Name 3"), 
Jump.Height = c(0.2684, 0.2627, 0.2491, 0.2557, 0.2655, 0.2496, 
0.3306, 0.3172, 0.3173, 0.3174, 0.297, 0.2795, 0.3509, 0.3564, 
0.3431, 0.323, 0.3355, 0.319), Av.Jump = c(0.26475, 0.26115, 
0.243, 0.25765, 0.25515, 0.24985, 0.3303, 0.3225, 0.30655, 
0.303, 0.2858, 0.28105, 0.3572, 0.3531, 0.33605, 0.3223, 
0.3293, 0.3287), RSI = c(0.6604, 0.5938, 0.6699, 0.6778, 
0.5531, 0.582, 0.5757, 0.4755, 0.5578, 0.5806, 0.5561, 0.5353, 
0.8394, 0.769, 0.7003, 0.5834, 0.7001, 0.6445), Av.RSI = c(0.6387, 
0.6467, 0.6314, 0.6416, 0.56815, 0.5982, 0.5465, 0.5025, 
0.581, 0.5956, 0.53685, 0.54515, 0.80915, 0.78775, 0.7029, 
0.58035, 0.64575, 0.6358)), row.names = c(1L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 
9L, 11L, 13L, 15L, 17L, 19L, 21L, 23L, 25L, 27L, 29L, 31L, 33L, 
35L), class = "data.frame")
```

## dashboard code

````
---
  title: "CMJ Data"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
  orientation: columns
social: menu
source_code: embed
runtime: shiny

---
  
  ```{r global, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
jumps <- read.csv("jumps v2.csv")
jumps2 <- subset(jumps, Av.Jump >= 0)
```


Column {.sidebar}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
  
  ```{r}
selectInput("selectInput1", "select Name:", 
            choices = unique(jumps2$Name))
```
```{r}
selectedData = reactive({
  jumps2[jumps2$Name == input$selectInput1, c(1,4)]
})
```

Column A
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
  
  ### K Means
  
  ```{r}
renderPlot({
  ggplot(selectedData(), aes(x = Date , y = Av.Jump, group = Name))+
    geom_line()
})
```
````

## Working dataset

```
structure(list(Date = c("2/20/2023", "2/13/2023", "2/6/2023", 
"1/30/2023", "1/23/2023", "1/16/2023"), Name = c("Name 1", "Name 1", 
"Name 1", "Name 1", "Name 1", "Name 1"), Jump.Height = c(0.2684, 
0.2627, 0.2491, 0.2557, 0.2655, 0.2496), Av.Jump = c(0.26475, 
0.26115, 0.243, 0.25765, 0.25515, 0.24985), RSI = c(0.6604, 0.5938, 
0.6699, 0.6778, 0.5531, 0.582), Av.RSI = c(0.6387, 0.6467, 0.6314, 
0.6416, 0.56815, 0.5982)), row.names = c(1L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 9L, 
11L), class = "data.frame")
>
```

## Working Code

```
ggplot(jumps3, aes(x = Date , y = Av.Jump, group = Name))+
geom_line()`
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that using `jumps2[jumps2$Name == input$selectInput1, c(1,4)]` you selected only two of the three columns needed for your plot. Use `jumps2[jumps2$Name == input$selectInput1, c("Date", "Name", "Av.Jump")]` instead:

````
---
title: "CMJ Data"
output: 
flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
orientation: columns
social: menu
source_code: embed
runtime: shiny
---

```{r global, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)

jumps2 <- structure(list(
  Date = c(
    "2/20/2023", "2/13/2023", "2/6/2023",
    "1/30/2023", "1/23/2023", "1/16/2023", "2/20/2023", "2/13/2023",
    "2/6/2023", "1/30/2023", "1/23/2023", "1/16/2023", "2/20/2023",
    "2/13/2023", "2/6/2023", "1/30/2023", "1/23/2023", "1/16/2023"
  ), Name = c(
    "Name 1", "Name 1", "Name 1", "Name 1", "Name 1",
    "Name 1", "Name 2", "Name 2", "Name 2", "Name 2", "Name 2", "Name 2",
    "Name 3", "Name 3", "Name 3", "Name 3", "Name 3", "Name 3"
  ),
  Jump.Height = c(
    0.2684, 0.2627, 0.2491, 0.2557, 0.2655, 0.2496,
    0.3306, 0.3172, 0.3173, 0.3174, 0.297, 0.2795, 0.3509, 0.3564,
    0.3431, 0.323, 0.3355, 0.319
  ), Av.Jump = c(
    0.26475, 0.26115,
    0.243, 0.25765, 0.25515, 0.24985, 0.3303, 0.3225, 0.30655,
    0.303, 0.2858, 0.28105, 0.3572, 0.3531, 0.33605, 0.3223,
    0.3293, 0.3287
  ), RSI = c(
    0.6604, 0.5938, 0.6699, 0.6778,
    0.5531, 0.582, 0.5757, 0.4755, 0.5578, 0.5806, 0.5561, 0.5353,
    0.8394, 0.769, 0.7003, 0.5834, 0.7001, 0.6445
  ), Av.RSI = c(
    0.6387,
    0.6467, 0.6314, 0.6416, 0.56815, 0.5982, 0.5465, 0.5025,
    0.581, 0.5956, 0.53685, 0.54515, 0.80915, 0.78775, 0.7029,
    0.58035, 0.64575, 0.6358
  )
), row.names = c(
  1L, 3L, 5L, 7L,
  9L, 11L, 13L, 15L, 17L, 19L, 21L, 23L, 25L, 27L, 29L, 31L, 33L,
  35L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Column {.sidebar}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

```{r}
selectInput("selectInput1", "select Name:",
  choices = unique(jumps2$Name)
)
```

```{r}
selectedData <- reactive({
  jumps2[jumps2$Name == input$selectInput1, c("Date", "Name", "Av.Jump")]
})
```

Column A
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

### K Means

```{r}
renderPlot({
  print(selectedData())
  ggplot(selectedData(), aes(x = Date, y = Av.Jump, group = Name)) +
    geom_line()
})
```
````

[image]